# UPS API Failure: Invalid Access License number

Tags: php, api, oauth, ups

I'm using PHP UPS API (https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api) to get rates and to hopefully generate labels.

I've logged into UPS and set up credentials. I have Client Id and Client Secret and successfully generated my access_token via curl. I have endpoints set up for testing and production and things seem to be working fine, until I try to issue a Rate call

$shipFrom and $shipTo are set up properly...

```
try {
    $shipment = new \Ups\Entity\Shipment();

    $shipFrom = new \Ups\Entity\ShipFrom();
    $shipFrom->setAddress($address_from);
    $shipment->setShipFrom($shipFrom);

    $shipTo = $shipment->getShipTo();
    $shipTo = $shipTo->setAddress($address_to);

    $package = new \Ups\Entity\Package();
    $package->getPackagingType()->setCode(\Ups\Entity\PackagingType::PT_PACKAGE);
    $package->getPackageWeight()->setWeight($weight);
    
    // if you need this (depends of the shipper country)
    $weightUnit = new \Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement;
    $weightUnit->setCode(\Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement::UOM_LBS);
    $package->getPackageWeight()->setUnitOfMeasurement($weightUnit);

    $dimensions = new \Ups\Entity\Dimensions();
    $dimensions->setHeight($height);
    $dimensions->setWidth($width);
    $dimensions->setLength($length);

    $unit = new \Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement;
    $unit->setCode(\Ups\Entity\UnitOfMeasurement::UOM_IN);

    $dimensions->setUnitOfMeasurement($unit);
    $package->setDimensions($dimensions);

    $shipment->addPackage($package);

    var_dump($rate->getRate($shipment));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

The exception is caught and I see this:

```
object(Ups\Exception\InvalidResponseException)#31 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(47) "Failure: Invalid Access License number (250003)"
```

This object is requiring $accessKey, $userId, $password.

I was assuming $accessKey would be my $accessToken. I'm believing that is incorrect. So where can I get an access key?

When I go here:
https://www.ups.com/dpui/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US

When I select: "I want to integrate UPS technology into my business"

It will only have the text below available:

"Note: We are excited to show you our new Developer Portal where you can get OAuth credentials to integrate with our APIs. Please click here to get started"

When I click 'get started', I'm back to my developer portal
https://developer.ups.com/en-us/

If I click on Apps -> My App Name, I see the id and secret again. Nothing mentioning access key.

I feel like I'm missing a major step somewhere.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Running into a similar issue

Comment: No. Just ended up going with Shippo and using their API

Answer (score 2):

Except when you are getting an access token, you need to have `/api` in the URL, so

[https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/{number}](https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/%7Bnumber%7D)
[https://wwwcie.ups.com/track/v1/details/{number}](https://wwwcie.ups.com/track/v1/details/%7Bnumber%7D)

becomes

[https://onlinetools.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/{number}](https://onlinetools.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/%7Bnumber%7D)
[https://wwwcie.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/{number}](https://wwwcie.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/%7Bnumber%7D)

This nearly broke me.

Comment: Thank you!!!! That was way too easy to miss. And the error message from the API was entirely unhelpful.